# Determining if a test measurement is from an empirical control distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, control-group

I have a sample of 100 measurements from a control population. These measurements are not that close to a normal distribution.

I also have made a single measurement that received a treatment.

Is there a statistical test I can use to establish the probability that the treatment had an effect?

Comment: You probably can't do an effective test.  You could apply an outlier detection test.  But it would only call it an outlier if it is far removed from the bulk of the control sample. Also say that one observation from the treatment group is an outlier is not the same as saying that the treatment group has a different mean from the control group.

Comment: would a one sample t-test be appropriate?  for the opposite problem (100 treatment samples against a population mean + variance) it seem it would be. Not sure if one can switch the sample and population though?

Comment: No because you have two samples and a two sample t test will not be possible unless you assume the two variances are equal. In any event the test would have very little power (because of only 1 sample in the second population.

Comment: It might help to give a bit more context; explaining what assumptions you're prepared to make, including those about the nature of the hypothesized effect.

Comment: @whuber suggested that I read more about prediction intervals, however I haven't found their use outside of linear models.